# C - While loop error

Tags: c, algorithm

im trying understand why i get this output, i put a while loop to go out to another method, i dont know why it doesnt working! the operation on debug show me value 1, the same condition to intry on the if clausule and invoke the register method to print "Test" on the screen.

```
//Struct Student
typedef struct {

    char name[50];
    float grade[4];
    int status;

} Student;

Student students[MAX_STUDENT];

//Methods Statements
void menu();
void registerStudent();
void deleteStudent();
void reproved();
void search();

int operation;  

int main() {

    menu();
    return 0;
}

//Display menu
void menu(){

    system("cls");   

    while(operation != 5){


        printf("1 - Register Student\n");
        printf("2 - Delete Student\n");
        printf("3 - Reproved Students\n");
        printf("4 - Find Student\n");
        printf("5 - Exit\n");
        scanf("%i", &operation);    

        if(operation == 1){
            registerStudent();
        }   

    };

}

void registerStudent(){

    char name[50];
float grade[4];

int op;
int i;

while(op != 0){

    system("cls");
    printf("Type the name: ");
    //Fgets to read line
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    printf("First two months: ");
    scanf("%f", &grade[0]);
    printf("Second two months: ");
    scanf("%f", &grade[1]);
    printf("Third two months: ");
    scanf("%f", &grade[2]);
    printf("Fouth two months: ");
    scanf("%f", &grade[3]);
    printf("1 - Continue\n");
    printf("0 - Exit\n");

    for(i=0; i<MAX_STUDENT; i++){

        if(students[i].status == 0){

            students[i].grade[0] = grade[0];
            students[i].grade[1] = grade[1];
            students[i].grade[2] = grade[2];
            students[i].grade[3] = grade[3];
            strcpy(students[i].name, name);
            break;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: Now its working!

Comment: it works for me. Make sure you have all the necessary `#include` files.

Comment: Put a newline after `test`.

Comment: The `while()` loop ends when they type 5, but the menu says 0.

Comment: Sorry for mistake, i fixed it, i put 5 again on the menu, but still not working!

Comment: Sorry guys, now i add more functionality on the method and its working!

Comment: MAX_STUDENT is not declared and you have to put an \n in the start of your menu. The rests works for me.

Comment: MAX_STUDENT is declared on my global statement, but i didn't paste here! but thanks for you help, now its working, i don't how i do this but... its working! Thanks!

Comment: Please read about [mcve] for the future. Please provide textual info as text, not as picture. Please make an answer of what finally solved your problem (assuming the existing answer did not do the trick) and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In `menu()` `operation` is used uninitialized and in `registerStudent()` `op` is also used uninitialized.